# What SQL Server data type can be divided and reconstituted accurately

Tags: sql-server

Consider the T-SQL code below. I want to allocate 10 units to a,b,c where it is prorated based on the current values of a,b,c.

For this case,

```
select @a + @b + @c
```

after the calculation is exactly 10 as expected.

However, in my client application, the values are returned from a stored procedure as

```
4.72222222222222, 4.72222222222222, 0.555555555555556
```

And when summed together, they come to 9.999999999999996

Crudely, the problem seems to be that there is a missing 2 from the end of both the 4.72222222222222 values, and if I manually add them in, the result = 10 as expected.

Conversely, if 0.555555555555556 had one less 5, eg 0.55555555555556, the summed result = 10.

Can anyone suggest how this might be handled elegantly?  The precision of each result is not that important, but it is important that they always sum back to the original `@adjustby`.

```
declare @totalOwned float
declare @adjustby float
declare @a float
declare @b float
declare @c float

set @adjustby = 10
set @a = 85
set @b = 85
set @c = 10

set @totalOwned = @a + @b + @c 

select @a = @adjustby * (@a/@totalOwned)
select @b = @adjustby * (@b/@totalOwned)
select @c = @adjustby * (@c/@totalOwned)

select @a + @b + @c,@a,@b,@c
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to to with SQL Server. it's normal behaviour of IEEE floating-point numbers. They are approximate values and not exact values - read for instance the [floating-point-guide](http://floating-point-gui.de).

You may get the expected results by rounding the end result, however this doesn't guarantee the correct result either. If you need to get back to the original result you need to avoid floating-point numbers.

Comment: I understand that, however based on experimentation, the decimal data type creates even stranger results.  Perhaps you could post a version of the t-sql that does reconstitute itself to 10, then I would accept.

Comment: Decimal is basically an integer where the comma is set at a specific (decimal) digit - as such it has completely different properties. One is that is is much less suitable for most divisions. In your case one solution may be to store the quotient and dividend as-is and sum them before doing the division - that would return the original result.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a think about how I might do that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `float`, use the `decimal` data type.  A decimal is declared:

```
declare @d decimal(p,s)
```

`p` is the precision, or total number of decimal digits that can be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point.

`s` is the scale, or number of decimal digits that can be stored to the right of the decimal point.

So to store `4.72222222222222`, you'd need at minimum `decimal(15,14)`.  15 decimals, of which 14 are behind the decimal point.

Comment: I understand that, however based on experimentation, the decimal data type creates even stranger results. Perhaps you could post a version of the t-sql that does reconstitute itself to 10.  Also, the data I am dealing with (eg the values of @a,@b,@c) has values from 0 to 100,000,000, so it isn't really possible to know what p,s would work for all cases.  For example, decimal(15,14) won't even work for this contrived example, because you need at least 3 numbers to the left of the decimal point.